# if statement not excluding empty string variables

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement

I am just wondering (and I'm stumped), why the if statement isn't working as it should. Have I missed something simple?

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -e "\nFinding the thing things on the thing, presently.\n"

DEVICE=$1
IPADDRESS=$(/sbin/ifconfig $DEVICE | grep -A 0 'inet addr:' | cut -c21-29)

for i in {1..255}
do
    HOST=$(ping -c 1 $IPADDRESS.$i | grep -A 0 'from' | cut -c15-25)
    if ["$HOST" != ""]
    then
        echo "$HOST is ALIVE!!!"
    fi
done
```

Comment: You need spaces around `[` and `]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add spaces between:

```
if [ "$HOST" != "" ]
```